# Expression Binding to format number values

Tags: javascript, sapui5

our oData is returning the below value.

> "this is test 870.00 and 250.00"

Our requirement is to remove the decimals from the string during the run time of the app on the View. Below is my binding.

```
<Text text="{path:'oTesTableModel>score',formatter:'publicservices.scr.myscorereq.util.Formatter.score'}"/>
```

can some one suggest if we can use expression binding to remove the decimals from the string and if yes can please provide some example.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of the in built Number Formatter.

```
<Text text="{path:'oTesTableModel>score',type:'sap.ui.model.type.Integer'}"/>
```

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.40.9/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.core.sample.TypeInteger/preview

Comment: Just saw that you have the numbers as part of a sentence! Just use a regex as part of your formatter.
return <string>.replace(/[.0]+/g,"");

Answer (score -1):

Try this

`<Text text="{= Math.floor(${oTesTableModel>score}) }"></Text>`

Comment: Wait a second...the "oTesTableModel>score" value is a number?? Or is it the whole sentence "this is test 870.00 and 250.00"???

Comment: If it is the sentence, there is no way to delete the decimals without splitting the sentence to get the numbers only. And this can't be done with Expression Binding. You need to use a formatter or floor() the numbers before building the sentence